# Mathematical representation of likelihood

Tags: machine-learning, probability

Likelihood is dealing with fitting models given some known data ...so does it implies **p(y|x)**...??
As much I know, likelihood formula is p(x|y). So it do contradict with the definition. Please explain.

Comment: hi! first this question if off topic for SO as it is not about programming. second, you may want to elaborate a little the question for it to be answerable

Comment: Good question, but not suitable for SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

We can usually interpret the likelihood in a machine learning model as the probability of observing ***y*** when the model is given ***x***.
The maximum likelihood estimator can be derived as the product sum of the conditioned probabilities:

[image]

or just

[image]

That is, the probability of observing the i'th output ***y***, when we give the i'th input ***x*** to some model with hypothesis ***h***.

For reference, you could consider a multivariate regression model with regression coefficients ***w***. Naturally we want to maximize the likelihood, by searching for some  optimal weights ***w****. We can thus write the likelihood as

[image]

Hope it clarifies a bit :)